# Why does mdadm believe my raid1 "has failed so using --add cannot work"?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

**TLDR:** Trying to add a blank partition to a degraded RAID1 with mdadm 3.3.2 (Debian Jessie) fails, saying the (perfectly working!) array has "failed" and "--add cannot work". Is it telling me of a real danger here, or have I just hit some weird bug?

## Detailed Version

Overnight, I had a disk die. There are 5 mdraid arrays on the box; one of them (a RAID10) rebuilt as expected using a spare. A RAID6 remains degraded until a replacement disk arrives tonight. Same with a 5-disk mirror for /boot. There are two RAID1 arrays used for swap; they share a hot spare. The hot spare was attached to the one which didn't experience a failure, but they're both in the same spare group, so `mdadm --monitor` attempted to move the spare—but it failed. Didn't give an error so far as I can tell, just lost the spare.

This morning, the degraded mirror looks like:

```
md124 : active raid1 sda2[0](F) sdc2[2]
      9767448 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 0/150 pages [0KB], 32KB chunk
```

I tried to manually add the spare, and got:

```
# mdadm -a /dev/md124 /dev/sdj2 
mdadm: /dev/md124 has failed so using --add cannot work and might destroy
mdadm: data on /dev/sdj2.  You should stop the array and re-assemble it.
```

`/dev/sdj2` had the superblock for the other mirror on it (as a spare in that mirror), so I went ahead and tried `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdj2`, but even after that, the add fails with the same error. I'm pretty sure I can make this work (e.g., I haven't tried `--force` yet, or `mdadm -r` on the failed disk—or worst case—its just swap—recreate the array).

I've gone ahead and stopped using that array for now (it was used for swap). `swapoff` performed I/O to the array without error, so it doesn't seem failed.

Doesn't appear to be a too-small device:

```
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdj2 
10001940480
10001940480
```

So I'm hoping someone else knows what this error means.

This is mdadm 3.3.2 (Debian Jessie) if it matters.

### mdadm -D

```
# mdadm -D /dev/md124 
/dev/md124:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Mar 11 20:34:00 2010
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 9767448 (9.31 GiB 10.00 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9767448 (9.31 GiB 10.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Mon Oct 12 12:35:13 2015
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : Einstein:swap_a  (local to host Einstein)
           UUID : 3d7da9d2:5ea17db5:3b122196:11968e91
         Events : 2044

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       2       8       34        1      active sync   /dev/sdc2

       0       8        2        -      faulty   /dev/sda2
```

### mdadm -E

```
# mdadm -E /dev/sdc2
/dev/sdc2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 3d7da9d2:5ea17db5:3b122196:11968e91
           Name : Einstein:swap_a  (local to host Einstein)
  Creation Time : Thu Mar 11 20:34:00 2010
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 19534897 (9.31 GiB 10.00 GB)
     Array Size : 9767448 (9.31 GiB 10.00 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 19534896 (9.31 GiB 10.00 GB)
    Data Offset : 144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 95e09398:1c155ebd:323371cf:a3acc3ad

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Oct 12 12:35:13 2015
       Checksum : 132239e4 - correct
         Events : 2044


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

# mdadm -E /dev/sdj2 
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdj2.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tracing through `mdadm` with `gdb` led me to a loop that attempted to scan through the array, looking for all the sync'd devices. Except it stopped early, before it found the working sdc2. With the buggy line of code in hand:

```
for (d = 0; d < MAX_DISKS && found < array->active_disks; d++) {
```

it was fairly easy to find this was fixed in mdadm git:

```
commit d180d2aa2a1770af1ab8520d6362ba331400512f
Author: NeilBrown <neilb@suse.de>
Date:   Wed May 6 15:03:50 2015 +1000

    Manage: fix test for 'is array failed'.

    We 'active_disks' does not count spares, so if array is rebuilding,
    this will not necessarily find all devices, so may report an array
    as failed when it isn't.

    Counting up to nr_disks is better.

    Signed-off-by: NeilBrown <neilb@suse.de>

diff --git a/Manage.c b/Manage.c
index d3cfb55..225af81 100644
--- a/Manage.c
+++ b/Manage.c
@@ -827,7 +827,7 @@ int Manage_add(int fd, int tfd, struct mddev_dev *dv,
                        int d;
                        int found = 0;

-                       for (d = 0; d < MAX_DISKS && found < array->active_disks; d++) {
+                       for (d = 0; d < MAX_DISKS && found < array->nr_disks; d++) {
                                disc.number = d;
                                if (ioctl(fd, GET_DISK_INFO, &disc))
                                        continue;
```

Applying that patch to mdadm fixes the problem. Though oddly after adding the disk, even though `/proc/mdstat` showed the spare present, it didn't start rebuilding until I stopped and re-assembled the array.